# Shipping method and shipping service from a placed order

Tags: 8, entities, commerce

I am trying to get the shipping method and the shipping service values after i place an order on a Drupal 8 commerce website so i can use it inside an email im sending the website's owner (not the receipt for the client). I know Swift email would be an option but i have to continue with what i have. So far the owner of the website does receive an email but i need to add more information to it like the shipping method and shipping service.

I've got as far as finding out that $order->shipments->entity  will give me, among other values, these 2 fields shipping_method and shipping_service.

```
Shipment {#4521 ▼
  #values: array:19 [▼
    "shipment_id" => array:1 [▶]
    "type" => array:1 [▶]
    "uuid" => array:1 [▶]
    "order_id" => array:1 [▶]
    "package_type" => array:1 [▶]
    "shipping_method" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "2"
    ]
    "shipping_service" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT"
    ]
```

Where do I find the values of the shipping method value whose ID is 2 and the shipping service value whose ID is PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since *shipping_method* is an entity reference field, you can use `$order->shipments->entity->shipping_method->entity` to get the referenced entity.

`$order->shipments->entity->shipping_service` is not a entity field, so you get its value with `$order->shipments->entity->shipping_service->value`.